# I can't understand why "FindRoot::nlnum:" shows up in my code... [edited]

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I want to solve a system of equations using Findroot as follows:

```
Clear[a]; Clear[c]; n = 2;
SysEqn1 = Table[a[i] + I Sum[(PolyLog[1, E^(I (c[j] - a[i] + 0.5))] + 
    PolyLog[1, E^(I (c[j] - a[i] + (2 \[Pi] - 1.2)))] - 
    PolyLog[1, E^(I (c[j] - a[i] - 0.3))] - 
    PolyLog[1, E^(I (c[j] - a[i] - 0.4))]), {i, n}], {j, n}];
SysEqn2 = Table[c[i] + I Sum[(PolyLog[1, E^(I (c[j] - a[i] + 0.5))] + 
    PolyLog[1, E^(I (c[j] - a[i] + (2 \[Pi] - 1.2)))] - 
    PolyLog[1, E^(I (c[j] - a[i] - 0.3))] - 
    PolyLog[1, E^(I (c[j] - a[i] - 0.4))]), {i, n}], {j, n}];
SysEqn = Join[SysEqn1, SysEqn2]; 
startingValues1 = Table[{a[i], -1 + 2 i/n}, {i, n}]; 
startingValues2 = Table[{c[i], -0.9 + 2 i/n}, {i, n}]; 
starting = Join[startingValues1, startingValues2];
FindRoot[SysEqn, starting]
```

The error message from the above code is as fo

```
FindRoot::nlnum: "The function value {a[i]+(0. +1.\ I)\ (1.\ Log[1. +Times[<<2>>]]+1.\ Log[1. +Times[<<2>>]]-1.\ Log[1. +Times[<<2>>]]-1.\ Log[1. +Times[<<2>>]]+1.\ Log[1. +Times[<<2>>]]+1.\ Log[1. +Times[<<2>>]]-1.\ Log[1. +Times[<<2>>]]-1.\ Log[1. +Times[<<2>>]]),a[i]+(0. +1.\ I)\ (<<1>>),<<1>>,c[i]+(0. +1.\ I)\ (1.\ Log[1. +Times[<<2>>]]+<<11>>)} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {4} at {a[1],a[2],c[1],c[2]} = {0.,1.,0.1,1.1}."
```

For n=2 case, I have four equations so I think the number of starting variables that should be determined is also four. But for some reason my code doesn't work... I would really appreciate if you can help me out with this problem!